# Why is the PnP Search Results web part not sorting library titles?

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-search-webparts

I am using SharePoint online.
Within a particular site I wanted a page in SitePages to display a sorted list of all the libraries in the site.
I mapped the following Managed Properties as shown at the tenancy level.

As far as I know, it is not possible to initiate a full crawl at the tenancy level.
[image]

I verified that the new values for these managed properties had automatically appeared in the site search schema.
I then re-indexed the site, and waited for an hour or so.
I then added the PnP Search Results web part on the page.

**Config Section 1**

I set Search query keywords to: *

**Config Section 2**

I then used the following code to include all libraries, but exclude ‘system’ libraries:

Query Template:

-"Site Pages"  -"Form Templates" -"Site Assets"  -"Documents" -"Style Library" path:"https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/Staff2Student" (contentclass:STS_List_DocumentLibrary)

Edit Sort Order

I did not create any default sort orders here.

Edit Sortable Fields

These are the sortable fields I created:

[image]

The two managed properties then appear in the ‘Sort by’ dropdown, but selection of either has no effect on the sort order of the libraries displayed.
I presume I am missing something obvious here – any thoughts or pointers will be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance,

Jimmy

Comment: PS In Config Section 3, if you chose layout 'Details List' it is possible to then sort on library title, but the default sort order appears to be random which looks bad and will confuse the users, and ideally I want a tiled layout. In 'Edit Sortable Fields' above, it is not possible to enter 'Title' as a sort managed property - an error message saying 'This property is not sortable' - that's why I have mapped Title and ows_Title to RefinableStrings. I have spent a lot of time trying to achieve something I thought would be quite straightforward!